# X Editable datetime icons not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

Im using X Editable to manipulate client side data. One of the components however (datetime), is not displaying the left and right icons used when switching between values (previous month, next month) for example.

After some googling, it seems that this is an issue with  X Editable as Bootstrap switched to Glyphicons from just icons and X Editable has not caught up. I can't find any reference to the prev-next buttons in the CSS, but did find this in the JS file:

```
if (this.o.rtl){
    this.picker.addClass('datepicker-rtl');
    this.picker.find('.prev i, .next i')
               .toggleClass('icon-arrow-left icon-arrow-right');
}
```

The icon-arrow-left and icon-arrow-right classes are NOT in the CSS file. My question is, how should I build these classes to display Glyphicons?

Comment: any luck figuring it out?

Comment: Here is [the issue](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/435) for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, this is works for me

```
.prev:before {
    content: "\2190 ";
}

.next:before {
    content: "\2192 ";
}
```

Comment: Good workaround, but these Unicode symbols just don't look right. `font-family: FontAwesome;` and `\f060` & `\f061` as content look better.

Comment: Alternatively, `font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';` and `\e091` & `\e092` will do.

Comment: hello @mlt , i m having strange issue with solution you provided in comment, my calendar is only showing one arrow whichever is written second in the following code only prev arrow button is showed not next, pls help: .next:before { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; content: "\f061 "; } .prev:before { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; content: "\f060 "; } can you pls help me to show both arrows for navigation of calendar, thanks a lot

Comment: @Aqeel Don't ask questions in comments.. especially about other comments. Perhaps you have something that overrides your style settings with a higher priority. Inspect the element with your browser's dev tools.